# Checkboxes inside dropdown menu php

Tags: php

I want to create dropdown menu with multiple checkboxes using framework of cakephp.

For example:

I have a dropdown having four options respectively--

a

b

c

d

Now I want checkboxes before each option.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the default `<select>` and `<option>` HTML tags, so I'd recommend using a javascript plugin such as [Dropdown Check List](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/)  (jQuery)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I will try some jQuery plugin.